# Offset individual copied columns with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying a set of individual columns from one workbook and pasting them to another. I want to offset what row my data is copied to (for example down 9 rows). I've tried to use the property:

```
.Offset()
```

But I don't know how to add it to my existing code.

```
Sub T1()
Dim sourceTitle As Range, targetTitle As Range

Set sourceTitle = Workbooks("Data to Copy.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("B")
Set targetTitle = Workbooks("Data Destination.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")

Set sourceProject = Workbooks("Data to Copy.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("C")
Set targetProject = Workbooks("Data 
Destination.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("D")

Set sourcePM = Workbooks("Data to Copy.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("D")
Set targetPM = Workbooks("Data Destination.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("I")

Set sourceBusiness = Workbooks("Data to Copy.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("E")
Set targetBusiness = Workbooks("Data Destination.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("K")

Set sourceHigh = Workbooks("Data to Copy.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("F")
Set targetHigh = Workbooks("Data Destination.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("L")

Set sourceE0 = Workbooks("Data to Copy.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("G")
Set targetE0 = Workbooks("Data Destination.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("S")

Set sourceActual = Workbooks("Data to Copy.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("H")
Set targetActual = Workbooks("Data Destination.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("V")

sourceTitle.Copy Destination:=targetTitle
sourceProject.Copy Destination:=targetProject
sourcePM.Copy Destination:=targetPM
sourceBusiness.Copy Destination:=targetBusiness
sourceHigh.Copy Destination:=targetHigh
sourceE0.Copy Destination:=targetE0
sourceActual.Copy Destination:=targetActual
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot offset the row on full column references.  You will need to find the last row with data, limit your range to that then you can use the offset.

Comment: The format for Offset is usually something like:  `Range("B1" ).Offset(9, 0) = Value`  where 9 is rows and 0 is columns.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott and Mitch pointed out, you would need to have a selected range with a defined start and finish row/column.

You can do this with some dynamic code (per source sheet/column) with code similar to:

```
Dim LR as Long, col1 as String
col1 = "C" 'Change to whatever column you want to focus
With Sheets("NAME1")
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

You can then move the data using the now defined LR (LR = last row):

```
With Sheets("NAME1")
    .Range( .Cells(1, col1), .Cells(LR, col1)).Copy Sheets("NAME2").Cells(9,"D")
End With
```

You only need to specify the upper left cell when pasting into a destination range.